# How do I get a session Variable out of a class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, session

How do I call the variables out of the class?

Comment: Session variable or attribute of a class? Not clear at all

Comment: @Alfabravo do you mean a property?

Comment: Well, don't know what you call a property but well, check @Toast answer... it covers all bases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by session you mean $_SESSION, you should be able to access this from anywhere.

If by session, you mean the member variabless of the class, that's a bit trickier.

```
class SomeClass()
{
    $name;
}

$someClass = new SomeClass();
echo $someClass->name;
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything with a class to access session variables in php.

Just use the superglobal [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Example:

```
print_r($_SESSION); // View all your session variables

echo $_SESSION['a_session_variable']; //Access a specific variable
```